# Roxygen2 - "argument is of length zero" error when documenting reference class

Tags: r, roxygen2, reference-class, roxygen

To demonstrate a minimal case, say I have the following package:

```
#' @docType package
#' @import methods
#' @title MyTitle
#' @description MyDescription
#' @details MyDetails
#' @export
A <- setRefClass("A")
```

When I `roxygenize` (in [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/), before a '[Build & Reload](http://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/packages/overview)'). I get:

```
==> roxygenize('.', roclets=c('rd', 'collate', 'namespace'))

* checking for changes ... ERROR

Error in process.docType(partitum) : 
  Roclet processing error in block Test1.R:7
argument is of length zero
```

What's going wrong? How do I resolve this error?

**My setup:**

- Roxygen2 3.1.0

  - Using roxygen to generate (in RStudio):

    - Rd files
    - Collate field
    - NAMESPACE file
  - Automatically roxygenising when running (in RStudio):

    - R CMD check
    - Source and binary package builds
    - Build & Reload
- R: 3.0.2 (Frisbee Sailing)
- IDE: RStudio 0.98.490
- OS: Windows 8.1

Comment: Why do you have `@docType` package? Otherwise, I don't see anything obviously wrong with your roxygen block.

Comment: @Hadley - because I'm building a package, so shouldn't I have a `@doctype package`?

Comment: `@docType` is for documentation type, which here would be class (but can be omitted because it's autogenerated). You also don't usually explicitly label `@title`, `@description` and `@details`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where

```
#' @export
A <- setRefClass("A")
```

cause the same error, which I resolved using:

```
A <- setRefClass("A")
#' @export
A
```

Curiously, this was in a file that I had not modified in a while, so it's still a bit of a mystery...